VS Code extension code to work for JetBrains plugin as well
I have created VS Code extension using typescript and react. I want to know that with that same code it is possible to use that extension in JetBrains as well. Or is there any SDK provided by VS Code or JetBrains to convert code into JetBrains working code.
Any suggestion will be really helpful to make make same VS Code extension to use in JetBrains with all functionality.Or if there is some minimal effort required to make it work.
I have searched that if that possible or not. But I am not finding any possible solution.

Though I don't say this with 100% certainty, I imagine the answer is no. They use different languages (VS Code uses TypeScript/JavaScript, and JetBrains uses Kotlin/Java), different UI technologies (VS Code is based on the web DOM, and JetBrains IDEs use Java Swing (they have similarities, but are not one-to-one compatible)), and even if you could convert TS/JS to Kotlin/Java one-to-one, they have different (, continually evolving) feature sets and models, which is reflected in their extension/plugin APIs.
Aside: It's a similar story between VS Code and Visual Studio (and both are created and owned by the same company!). See also Is it possible to install VS Code extensions in Visual Studio or vice versa?.
